# Why does this method fail to instrument ActionView::Template :render?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, metaprogramming, mvc-mini-profiler

We are porting [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com) to Ruby and wanted to add auto instrumentation for Rails views and partials.

I am aware of the [existing instrumentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Notifications.html) support but ideally want to get "start" and "stop" events. We would also like to support earlier versions of Rails that do not have notification support.

I hacked up a short instrumenter and tested hooking up render with *before* and *after* calls:

```
def prof(klass, method)
  with_profiling = (method.to_s + "_with_profiling").intern
  without_profiling = (method.to_s + "_without_profiling").intern

  klass.send :alias_method, without_profiling, method
  klass.send :define_method, with_profiling do |*args, &orig|
    puts "before #{method} #{args}"
    self.send without_profiling, *args, &orig
    puts "after #{method}"
  end
  klass.send :alias_method, method, with_profiling
end

prof ActionView::Template, :render
```

However, once this is activated `render` is not instrumented properly. In particular this works on some of the partials, but explodes with a:

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `html_safe' for nil:NilClass)

What is wrong with this method hook? What is a proper robust way to hook methods so they are not fragile to this problem (maintaining the trivial API: `prof klass, method`)

Comment: Any reason to favour `(method.to_s + "_with_profiling").intern` over `:"#{method}_with_profiling"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've redefined the method to return the result of your final `puts` which is usually `nil`. A fix might be:

```
klass.send :define_method, with_profiling do |*args, &orig|
  puts "before #{method} #{args}"
  result = self.send without_profiling, *args, &rig
  puts "after #{method}"

  result
end
```

Comment: wow ... can't believe I missed it, that will learn me to take a break from Ruby :)

Comment: now the follow up question I need to ask is how to get a sane view name from the hook